# Deploying Flow via Migration Tool, object "Campaign" can not be updated

Tags: deployment, flow

Am using the Migration Tool to move a bunch of stuff including Flows from one Sandbox to another. Am getting this error on several of the flows:

```
The object "Campaign" can't be updated through a flow.
```

Seems strange because the flows work in the source sandbox. Anyone seen this error before?

Comment: Are you trying to replace a flow that's already been deployed?

Comment: @crmprogdev no there are no Flows in the destination sandbox

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out:

The user I was doing the deploy with did not have the 'Marketing User' checkbox ticked in user settings - hence did not have access to the Campaign object.

Once I enabled 'Marketing User' the deploy was OK