# The object "TransactionJournal" can't be created through a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, loyalty-management

I have an auto-launched flow to create `TransactionJournal`. It works correctly in dev sandbox. When I try to deploy it to another dev sandbox, I get this error `The object "TransactionJournal" can't be created through a flow.`
I didn't find any documentation on this limitation. Is there any reason why I can create such a flow but can't deploy it?

Comment: Do you have 'Loyalty Management license' enabled for user ? (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/loyalty_api_overview.htm)

Comment: @Vinay you are right, that was the issue, thanks

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I will post same as an answer so that it can help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have permission for TransactionJournal object and 'TransactionJournal' object is available in Enterprise, Performance, Developer, and Unlimited Editions that have Loyalty Management license enabled.

Also, you can check loyalty management data model details [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/loyalty_management_data_model.htm) , to learn about the objects and relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer that suggests the error message you're seeing is more generally related to license/permissions

[Deploying Flow via Migration Tool, object "Campaign" can not be updated](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97339/deploying-flow-via-migration-tool-object-campaign-can-not-be-updated)

Their problem was resolved by giving the user the "Marketing User" permission. There may be a similar permission for TransactionJournal.